# Dynamically insert a new type of viewholder into a RecyclerView adapter

Tags: android

Is there a way to dynamically insert a new kind of `viewType` into a `RecyclerView.Adapter`, let's say I have the following:

```
//View Types
private static final int HEADER = 0;
private static final int OTHER_ITEM = 1;
```

And the following `getItemViewType` method:

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (position == 0)
        return HEADER;
    else
        return OTHER_ITEM;
}
```

The problem now is that I need to dynamically add a new kind of view type at a random specific place in the adapter. How would I go about accomplishing this?

So there would be another `ViewHolder` let's call it:

```
public class DynamicViewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
     ....
}
```

I would like to insert this randomly at random places in the adapter, how should I do this?

Comment: Generate a random number between 0 and getCount()-1, then if (position == randomPosition) return the new holder. Is this what you are asking?

Comment: I have an item that if the user taps, then they should see a new type of item after tapping that item maybe two or three items down the list if they keep scrolling down